# TabView does not preserve state when swiping from one tab to another

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-bloc

**Context:** Here's page that has a `TabView` to navigate between tabs all of these tabs are making use of `flutter_bloc` (version 6.0.1).

**Problem:** When swiping to to any tab, the state is not being preserved and the entire widget tree is being rebuilt as shown in the gif below

[image: PageView State not being preserved when swiping]

Here is the `build()` method:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: _buildAppBarWithTabs(),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            defaultViewforCategory(1), //Women
            defaultViewforCategory(3), //Men
            defaultViewforCategory(2), //Kids
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the implementation of the function `defaultViewforCategory()`

```
Widget defaultViewforCategory(int mainCategoryId) {
    return PageStorage(
      bucket: bucket,
      key: PageStorageKey(mainCategoryId),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 1200),
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 150),
              child: Container(
                height: 800,
                child: RefreshIndicator(
                  onRefresh: () => refreshTimeline(),
                  child: CustomScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    slivers: <Widget>[
                      SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: MasonryGrid(
                          column: getResponsiveColumnNumber(context, 1, 2, 6),
                          children: <Widget>[
                            // First Bloc
                            BlocProvider(
                              create: (context) {
                                BrandBloc(repository: _brandRepository);
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: 200,
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                height: 90,
                                child: BrandScreen(
                                  brandBloc: context.bloc(),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            CategoryScreen(
                              // Second Bloc
                              categoryBloc: CategoryBloc(
                                  mainCategoryId: mainCategoryId,
                                  repository: _categoryRepository),
                            ),

                            // -------------- Featured Items--------------------------
                            Container(
                              width: 200,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              height: 350,
                              child: _buildFeaturedItemsList(mainCategoryId),
                            ),
                            Placeholder(strokeWidth: 0, color: Colors.white)
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Tried-solutions:**
1 - I tried the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` but it turned out this `mixin` preserve the state of a page when switching to a another page using `BottomNavigationBar`.

2 - `PageStorage` didn't solve the problem.

**Question:** How to stop the `TabView` from being rebuilt each time the user swipes to another tab?

Comment: Maybe try changing `_buildAppBarWithTabs()` and `defaultViewforCategory` into widgets instead of functions? I read somewhere that it structures the widget tree differently when doing so..

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, one of the problems is that the `TabBarView` is rebuild every time the tab is presented. For that issue is an open topic [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19116). Because of that, a fresh new Bloc instance is created every time when screen changes.

**NOTE** Because the `CategoryBloc` is not passed using `BlocProvider` you should dispose the bloc manually.

A simple solution here is to move the `BlocProvider` up in the hierarchy outside of the `TabBarView` - by example, first component in the build method.

**NOTE** As performance wise this is okay because the BLOCs are lazily initialized when a bloc is requested.

Now the more delicate problem is the the way the `CategoryBloc` is created (because has a dynamic constructor). Here you can have two solution:

1. Either you modify the `CategoryBloc` to be shareable by all categories screen - here I can not help you too much because I don't have the code of it. The idea is to send the `mainCategoryId` through `events` and `emits` a new state with the results. In this case you should forward the `mainCategoryId` into the `state` and, on `BlocBuilder`, use `buildWhen` parameter to build only when the `mainCategoryId` matches the CategoryScreen id (which can be passed when the screen is created). AND to not forget also to provide the CategoryBloc using `BlocProvider` outside of the `TabBarView` child.
2. **OR** move the CategoryBloc creation outside of the TabBarView and cache them for further access. I have created an example below to emphasize this.

   ```
   // ...

   ///
   /// Categories blocs cache.
   ///
   Map<int, CategoryBloc> _categoriesBlocs;

   ///
   /// Creates UNIQUE instances of CategoryBloc by id.
   ///
   CategoryBloc getCategoryBlocById(int id) {
       // If you don't already have a bloc for that particular id, create a new one
       // and cache it (by saving it in the Map)
       this._categoriesBlocs.putIfAbsent(
           id,
           () => CategoryBloc(
           mainCategoryId: id,
                     repository: _categoryRepository,
           ));

       // Return the cached category bloc
       return this._categoriesBlocs[id];
     }

   ///
   /// This is very important. Because we manually create the BLOCs we have 
   /// to manually dispose them 
   ///
   @override
   void dispose() {
       for (var bloc in this._categoriesBlocs) {
        bloc.displose();
       }
       super.dispose();
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       super.build(context);

       return MultiBlocProvider(
           providers: [
               BlocProvider(
                   create: (context) => BrandBloc(repository: _brandRepository),
               )
           ],
           child: DefaultTabController(
               initialIndex: 0,
               length: 3,
               child: Scaffold(
                   backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                   appBar: _buildAppBarWithTabs(),
                   body: TabBarView(
                       children: <Widget>[
                           defaultViewforCategory(1), //Women
                           defaultViewforCategory(3), //Men
                           defaultViewforCategory(2), //Kids
                       ],
                   ),
               ),
           ),
       );
   }

     // ...

     CategoryScreen(
     // Second Bloc
     // Now, here you will get the same BLOC instance every time
         categoryBloc: getCategoryBlocById(mainCategoryId),
     ),

     // ...
   ```